# Repeat RSS Feed

Tags: windows, rss

I'm looking to take an existing RSS feed and duplicate it, (create a new feed that broadcasts content from the original feed).  Both feeds, the original and the duplicate, will be on an intranet and blocked from the outside world, so I can't leverage any online services that may exist.  Does anyone know of any existing applications that could be leveraged?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could script this in just a few lines, but you should be able to do this using a command line utility like wget (builtin on linux, [tiny downloadable executable for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)).

You could create a batch file (or just run the command below outright) that gets the original rss feed and outputs it to a file, then use task scheduler (on windows, not sure what on linux/unix/mac) to make it repeat say...every 15 minutes. Then on that machine, either with a web server you could make that file available as an rss file, or you might be able to just share it as a network share and access it from other computers (I doubt it though - can somebody clarify this?)

The syntax would be

```
wget url > file.rss
```

where "url" is the location of the original feed on your intranet and "file.rss" is the location where you want the new feed to live.

Comment: Crafty solution!

Comment: Glad to help and I hope it worked! I was thinking of scripts to write, then thought "what would people on superuser do" and remembered wget. Good luck.